# Backbone stickit - bind using class names and qualified "this"

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-stickit

I often find myself providing some sort of naming convention for `stickit` jQuery target `ID`s, in the form `some-aggregate-individual-element-{#number}` pairing each `ID` with a corresponding collection element in a one-to-one fashion. This is to ensure that `stickit` will update only the particular `View` in question and not other similar aggregate views.

It seems like there should be a way to use, say, class names rather than `ID`s for this purpose if you could somehow tell `stickit` the "root" node to perform updates under. For instance, if I am defining a `View` and I say `bindings: { ".individual-title": { observe: "Title" } }`, `stickit` knows that the `Title` attribute is coming from `this.model` so there is no need for qualification. However, whenever I apply the same logic to the left hand side, `stickit` performs updates against ALL nodes on the document with that class name rather than only those nodes that live under `this.$el`, where `$el` is the root node of my view.

Is there a built-in or otherwise easy way to achieve this so I can stop `id`ing all of my elements with silly naming conventions? Or is this what you are supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 2):

I actually bind to the name attribute on on the form element, therefore eliminating the use of ids and classnames. So for example lets say I have the following model.

```
User.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        firstname: null,
        lastname: null,
        phone: null,
        personemail: null
    }
});
```

I then create the following helpers:

```
// Create default binding therefore eliminating repetition
Backbone.View.prototype.createDefaultBindings = function() {
    var k, v, _ref, _results;
    this._bindings = {};
    _ref = this.model.toJSON();
    _results = [];
    for (k in _ref) {
        v = _ref[k];
        _results.push(this._bindings['input[name="' + k +'"]'] = { observe: k });
    }
    return _results;
};

// Helper to overide bindings in our view
Backbone.View.prototype.mergeBindings = function() {
    if (this.model) {
        this.createDefaultBindings();
    }
    _.extend(this._bindings, this.bindings);
    this.bindings = this._bindings;
};
```

Then we can have the following view:

```
User.Views.Form = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.mergeBindings();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.stickit();
    }
});
```

Initialize our view

```
var view = new User.Views.Form({ model: new User.Model() })
```

It would then bind to your template with the the following inputs:

```
<input name="firstname" type="text">
<input name="lastname" type="text">
<input name="phone" type="text">
<input name="email" type="text">
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for sharing your particular wiring/plumbing implementation. That helps! But what if you are not dealing with a form element, but instead a `span` or `h2` or `img` ?

Comment: I found the following in the docs `:el (selector)` (A special selector value that binds to the view delegate (view.$el)) - http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/#bindings/el-selector. So maybe you could do the following `:el .your-selector`? Let me know if that works. Quite curious. Will have a look at the source when I am at home as well.